# How to get content from vuex

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I cloned this simple admin dashboard made with [VueJs + AdminLTE](https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot) project into my local, so far everything works ... but I am currently struggling to find out how to get the stored state from vuex specially from [this line of code](https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot/blob/master/src/components/Login.vue#L76-L77) which I modified to:

```
// if user loggedin
if(response.data && response.status == 200){
  this.$store.commit("USERNAME", data.username)
  this.$store.commit("TEL", data.tel)
  this.$store.commit('EMAIL', data.email)

  this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
}
```

Once the page is redirected I am trying to get the username, tel, email but It doesn't exist.

I did `console.log(this.$store)` I see many contents but not the user info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.$store.commit("USERNAME", data.username)
```

Above code will not set the username to the store. You need to call corresponding mutation in your commit . For example

```
this.$store.commit("SET_USER", data);
```

It will set the corresponding user data to the 'user' state in the store.
Now you can  get the corresponding user info using

```
   `this.$store.state.user`
```

The above call will contains all the user info like email, tel, username etc

Comment: Just one question, why is the mutation needed? and if username is updated suddenly can vuex know about it? like the direct data binding of model

Comment: We can only change the state values using mutations. There is simple documentation for vuex  https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html